How to handle the navigation error in "Failed to fetch"
According to this answer on Stackoverflow, one of the reason a "Failed to fetch" can occur is because of navigation.

Browser aborted -- most likely due to navigation to another page before the fetch completes

How can I handle this specific error in simple fetch query?
fetch("https://xxx.yyy/").then(e => e);

I don't want to handle all "failed to fetch" error, only the ones that are triggered because of navigation.

Whats the reason for only needing the "Failed to fetch" errors? Seems peculiar.

Furthermore (adding to @Reyno's comment), the specific fetch call in the question, as written, won't navigate anywhere, it will "at best" return the resource at the specified URL, following 3xx HTTP responses on its way to the resource.

You can handle fetch-related errors with a call to the .catch() method of the Promise returned by calling fetch(). Also, if your page performs a full page load when you navigate (e. g. it's not an SPA) you simply do not have to handle them at all.

@Reyno The reason is that I want to handle other errors differently. But an error because I am navigating (such as reloading the page) could be ignored, or at least be handled differently than the 'failed to fetch" because of CORS issue. So my question is about doing specific work for a specific case (navigation)

I can think of only one way, to flag the navigation start and then check the flag in your handler.
Unfortunately, the navigate event is not very well supported so you might want to use beforeunload instead.
navigateStart = false;
addEventListener("navigate", (event) => {
    navigateStart = true;
});
fetch("https://xxx.yyy/").then(e => e).catch(e => {
    if (navigateStart) {
        // This is most likely due to a navigation, handle accordingly here.
    }
});


You could listen for the navigation event and then use an AbortController before they navigate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

The AbortController is used to abort the request, but OP asks for when it is being aborted by the browser.

@Salketer If it's aborted by the browser you don't have to handle it at all, because the browser already handled it.

What I meant is that they do not want to abort it themselves, they want to handle the error produced when the fetch is aborted.
